# How to count the special character in a column using SQL

Tags: sql

I have column which contains values like:

```
Column_1
3
4
-94#30#56#
56
730#-58#
```

If column value contains #, then count the number of # and replace those existing values.

My output should look like,

```
Column_1
3
4
3
56
2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use the SQL `REPLACE` function and compare the original length of a `Column_1` value containing `#` against the length with all `#` removed:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Column_1 LIKE '%#%'
         THEN CAST(LEN(Column_1) - LEN(REPLACE(Column_1, '#', '')) AS VARCHAR(100))
         ELSE Column_1 END AS Column_1
FROM yourTable;
```

I used SQL Server syntax, and the query would need to be adjusted for other databases.

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: Database is SparkSQL

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (len(Column_1) - len(replace(Column_1,'#',''))) > 0 
    THEN 
        (len(Column_1) - len(replace(Column_1,'#','')))  
    ELSE 
        Column_1 
    END 
FROM @tbl
```